# Adding class to a specific ng-multiselect-dropdown item

Tags: html, angular

I'm using `ng-multiselect-dropdown`, and I want to add a **class** to **specific items** on my lists.

##### HTML

```html
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
[data]="mydata"
[settings]="mysettings"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

##### TypeScript

Is there any way to do something like this?

```js
tempList[i] = { ...tempList[i], **cssClass: 'my css code'** };}
```

```js
getData() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe((resp: any) => {
      const tempList = resp;
      for (let i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++) {
        if(mycondition()){
            tempList[i] = { ...tempList[i], cssClass: 'my css code' };
        }
      }
      this.mydata = tempList;
    }, () => {

    });
}
```

Comment: Did you check the library you're using?

Comment: yes i did. unfortunately i couldn't find a way to do such thing, so i was thinking if maybe there is another alternative @Roy

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS to `multiselect-item-checkbox` in style.css

```
.multiselect-item-checkbox{
  background: cornflowerblue!important;
}
```

When you filter up using a condition, it means all objects in `mydata` should with one CSS style. so we can add the style Once.

[image]

Comment: i'm trying for example to apply the **multiselect-item-checkbox** for example to just some items of my list not all of them (for example only name1, name2, name3 should be on **cornflowerblue**). i'm not sure how can i achieve that with your suggestion

Comment: Please share a stackblitz